# How to set proxy To hide my IP address for scraping the webpage using dryscrape

Tags: python, proxy, web-scraping, scrape

I have a lot of active public proxys that i want to use to scrape some pages.

Can anyone give me an axample of how can i set a proxy in dryscrape?

https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape

I tried setting sys env http_proxy with python and didnt work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set proxy using `dryscrape.Session.set_proxy` method.

For example:

```
my_session = dryscrape.Session(base_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com')
my_session.set_proxy('127.0.0.1', 9000)
```

Comment: this is giving me the error: webkit_server.InvalidResponseError: {"class":"InvalidResponseError","message":"Unable to load URL: http://www.google.com/ because of error loading http://www.google.com/: Unknown error"}

Comment: Seems like my ambient was not configured properly

Comment: @RenatoPrado Hey, I'm hitting the same problem with "Unable to load URL ... because of error loading ..." I know this was a long time ago, but do you have a working solution going now? What's Ambient?

Comment: @DaveAaronSmith, sorry, I don't remember what was the problem.